# Dúvida sobre subselect em Firebird

Tags: sql, select, firebird

Eu tenho uma tabela que envolve a parte de entrada e saída de um caixa, um exemplo disto é:

No dia 01/01/2018 o usuário informou que entrou R$ 200,00 no cofre da empresa, no mesmo dia ele realizou outra operação de entrada no valor de R$ 800,00. Ao término do dia ele retirou R$ 500,00 totalizando o saldo do dia no valor de R$ 500,00 apenas referente as operações.

No meu banco de dados está descrito assim

```
Data       Op           Valor
01/01/2018 +            200
01/01/2018 +            800
01/01/2018 -            500
```

Está da mesma forma que está logo acima, eu gostaria de tentar pegar os valores de entrada menos os valores de saída, eu criei este `select`:

```
SELECT
SUM(SELECT A.DINHEIRO 
FROM TVENSANGRIASUPRIMENTO A 
WHERE A.OPERACAO = '+' 
AND A.IDSANGRIASUPRIMENTO = B.IDSANGRIASUPRIMENTO)

-

SUM(SELECT A.DINHEIRO 
FROM TVENSANGRIASUPRIMENTO A 
WHERE A.OPERACAO = '-' 
AND A.IDSANGRIASUPRIMENTO = B.IDSANGRIASUPRIMENTO)
FROM TVENSANGRIASUPRIMENTO B
```

Mas nada disso está dando certo.

Atenciosamente.

Answer (score 1):

Você não precisa de um SubSelect para isso, basta usar o [CASE](https://firebirdsql.org/refdocs/langrefupd15-case.html)

```
SELECT 
    CASE WHEN OPERACAO = '+' THEN SUM(DINHEIRO) END SaldoEntrada,
    CASE WHEN OPERACAO = '-' THEN SUM(DINHEIRO) END SaldoSaida, 
    (CASE WHEN OPERACAO = '+' THEN SUM(DINHEIRO) END) - (CASE WHEN OPERACAO = '-' THEN SUM(DINHEIRO) END) AS SaldoDiferenca

FROM TVENSANGRIASUPRIMENTO
```